# How can Antennahouse Formatter handle referenced footnotes?

Tags: xslt, xsl-fo, saxon, footnotes, antenna-house

I am developing a pdf print publication with xsl-fo (Saxon XSL 2.0, AHF V6.2).

My goal is to have auto-numbered footnotes (excluding duplicates on a single page) with inserted text from referenced static text elements.

So basically inline footnotes (fn) do reference a static footnote text element, create an inline number and print the according footnote text at the bottom of the page.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document>
<chapter>
    <paragraph>some description...</paragraph>
    <paragraph>some description with a footnote <fn id="fn2"/></paragraph>
    <paragraph>some description with a footnote <fn id="fn2"/></paragraph>
    <paragraph>some description...</paragraph>
    <paragraph>some description with a footnote <fn id="fn1"/></paragraph>
</chapter>
<!-- this is a wrapper element that will not be displayed in the rendered pdf but only contains the needed information for different footnote texts -->
<chapter class="footnoteWrapper">
    <footnote id="fn1">
        This is the text body of footnote #1.
    </footnote>
    <footnote id="fn2">
        This is the text body of footnote #2.
    </footnote>
    <footnote id="fn3">
        This is the text body of footnote #3.
    </footnote>
</chapter>
</document>
```

Duplicate inline footnotes in a chapter have to show the same number according to the footnote they are pointing to.

This is what the result should look like...

[image: Possible output]

Is it possible to achieve these goals with the AHF footnote extensions and the fo:footnote elements?

*The AntennaHouse Formatter extentions do deliver strange behaviour if I´m using them for fn counting. They do continue counting (1, 2, 3) instead of refereing to the correct and current number of the referenced footnote.*

This is the XSL so far (just the relevant snippet):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">

<xsl:template match="fn[@id = //footnote/@nodeid]"
    mode="content"
    priority="7">
    <!--+ fn link
        |
        | basic fn (inline) link template.
        |
        +-->
    <xsl:apply-templates select="//footnote[@id = current()/@id]"
        mode="content"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="footnote"
    mode="content"
    priority="5">
    <!--+ footnote
        |
        | basic footnote template.
        |
        +-->
    <fo:footnote xsl:use-attribute-sets="fnt.footnote">
        <fo:inline baseline-shift="super">
            <axf:footnote-number id="fn_{@id}"/>
        </fo:inline>
        <fo:footnote-body space-after="1mm">
            <fo:list-block provisional-distance-between-starts="5mm"
                provisional-label-separation="2mm">
                <fo:list-item>
                    <fo:list-item-label end-indent="label-end()">
                        <fo:block>
                            <fo:inline baseline-shift="super">
                                <axf:footnote-number-citation ref-id="fn_{@id}"/>
                            </fo:inline>
                        </fo:block>
                    </fo:list-item-label>
                    <fo:list-item-body start-indent="body-start()">
                        <fo:block>
                            <xsl:apply-templates mode="content"/>
                        </fo:block>
                    </fo:list-item-body>
                </fo:list-item>
            </fo:list-block>
        </fo:footnote-body>
    </fo:footnote>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Can you show us the relevant XSLT you have so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These changes generate the footnote the first time that the footnote is used and just generate the number for subsequent times:

```
<xsl:key name="fn" match="fn[exists(key('footnote', @id))]" use="@id" />
<xsl:key name="fn-first" match="fn[. is key('fn', @id)[1]]" use="@id" />
<xsl:key name="footnote" match="footnote" use="@id" />

<xsl:template match="fn[exists(key('footnote', @id))][. is key('fn-first', @id)]"
    mode="content"
    priority="7">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="key('footnote', @id)"
        mode="content">
        <xsl:with-param name="number" select="count(preceding::fn[. is key('fn-first', @id)]) + 1"></xsl:with-param>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="fn[exists(key('footnote', @id))][not(. is key('fn-first', @id))]"
    mode="content"
    priority="7">
    <fo:inline baseline-shift="super">
        <xsl:value-of select="count(key('fn-first', @id)/preceding::fn[. is key('fn-first', @id)]) + 1"/>
    </fo:inline>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="footnote" mode="content" priority="5">
    <xsl:param name="number" select="count(preceding-sibling::footnote) + 1" as="xs:integer" />
    <fo:footnote xsl:use-attribute-sets="fnt.footnote">
        <fo:inline baseline-shift="super">
            <xsl:value-of select="$number" />
        </fo:inline>
        <fo:footnote-body space-after="1mm">
            <fo:list-block provisional-distance-between-starts="5mm"
                provisional-label-separation="2mm">
                <fo:list-item>
                    <fo:list-item-label end-indent="label-end()">
                        <fo:block>
                            <fo:inline baseline-shift="super">
                                <xsl:value-of select="$number" />
                            </fo:inline>
                        </fo:block>
                    </fo:list-item-label>
                    <fo:list-item-body start-indent="body-start()">
                        <fo:block>
                            <xsl:apply-templates mode="content" />
                        </fo:block>
                    </fo:list-item-body>
                </fo:list-item>
            </fo:list-block>
        </fo:footnote-body>
    </fo:footnote>
</xsl:template>
```

You could tidy it up a bit more by, e.g., making a function that returns the `count()` value for a `fn`, but this should get you going.

See my other answer for how you can use both `axf:suppress-duplicate-footnote` and `axf:footnote-number` so duplicates are suppressed only when the duplicates are on the same page.

Answer (score 1):

The duplicate footnotes also had duplicate IDs.  The error from the non-unique IDs was getting in the way of the `axf:suppress-duplicate-footnote` processing.

If you're not making links to the footnotes, generate a unique ID for each footnote based on the `fn` that refers to it:

```
<xsl:template match="fn[exists(key('footnote', @id))]" mode="content" priority="7">
    <!--+ fn link
    |
    | basic fn (inline) link template.
    |
    +-->
    <xsl:apply-templates select="key('footnote', @id)" mode="content">
        <xsl:with-param name="id" select="generate-id()" />
    </xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="footnote" mode="content" priority="5">
    <xsl:param name="id" />
    <!--+ footnote
    |
    | basic footnote template.
    |
    +-->
    <fo:footnote xsl:use-attribute-sets="fnt.footnote" axf:suppress-duplicate-footnote="true">
        <fo:inline baseline-shift="super">
            <axf:footnote-number id="{$id}" />
        </fo:inline>
        <fo:footnote-body space-after="1mm">
            <fo:list-block provisional-distance-between-starts="5mm"
                provisional-label-separation="2mm">
                <fo:list-item>
                    <fo:list-item-label end-indent="label-end()">
                        <fo:block>
                            <fo:inline baseline-shift="super">
                                <axf:footnote-number-citation ref-id="{$id}" />
                            </fo:inline>
                        </fo:block>
                    </fo:list-item-label>
                    <fo:list-item-body start-indent="body-start()">
                        <fo:block>
                            <xsl:apply-templates mode="content" />
                        </fo:block>
                    </fo:list-item-body>
                </fo:list-item>
            </fo:list-block>
        </fo:footnote-body>
    </fo:footnote>
</xsl:template>
```